# CSS - Flexbox Justify spaced-between not working in IE 10-11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to understand why the below code doesn't work on IE 10 and 11.

```css
.accordion-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="accordion-title" aria-controls="w2zjml-accordion" role="tab" id="w2zjml-accordion-label" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false">
  <h4 class="heading-orange">Accordion 1</h4>
  <i class="icon icon-arrow-icon"></i>
</a>
```

The expected behaviour is that the h4 would be to the left and the icon to the right of the parent with both elements vertically centered.

This works on all other browsers but not on IE 10 and 11.

**Edit:** I should point out that in IE it centers the `<h4>` heading and indents the icon.

Comment: Working fine here in IE11 (and IE10 emulation): https://jsfiddle.net/eb5qLgj7/1/

Comment: Same as Michael_B. I can't duplicate your issue with the code given in IE11 or when emulating IE10.

Comment: hmm thanks guys. must be something else messing it up

Comment: Could be the `h4` being set to `display: inline;` somewhere?